# Providing Case Link on Message Template

Tags: civicase, tokens, message-templates

Upon assigning a role on a case, I wish to be able to send an email to the role. The email should include a link to the case. However, I am having trouble identifying what should the link be. The link that I am inputting is usually redirecting me to the wrong case. Could someone help me with this issue that I am facing? The following is a screenshot of the url that I have tried:
[image: Message Template]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `cid=` in the url. It looks like you have the casetokens extension installed - you could try `{case_roles.client_contact_id}` or maybe `{case_roles.client_id}`?

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly!